# Accounts and logins of the Stack Exchange sites family

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts

I have an account on Stack Overflow, for the past many years. Over the time I used other Stack Exchange sites as well, like *[TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* and *[Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/tour)*.
Yesterday I posted my first question on the *[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour)* site.

All the sites share my account data, *but* I need to log in to, e.g., the Database Administrators site separately even though I am already logged in to Stack Overflow.
I even got notified on Stack Overflow that somebody added a comment to the question on Database Administrators, but clicking on the notification, no automatic log in to Database Administrators site was done.

Should it be like this or should there be automated logins?